# Bicubic Interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

What is The Algorithm For ** Bi-cubic interpolation**?

I am doing this in MATLAB ( i m new to MATLAB). I have already done ** Bi-linear interpolation** but i don't know how to do bi-cubic interpolation.

Comment: interpolate over 1D? 2D? ND?

Comment: also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to implement it - read Wiki, link was posted by @robocop
If you need just the result - there is a Curve Fitting Toolbox for Matlab.

Also, I guess, bicubic stands for cubic interpolation for 2D data.

So, you can use `interp2` function with `method='cubic'` to get things done.
Read about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html?searchHighlight=interp2)